# Multiple Styling Logic to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply background colors to a data frame using 4 different masking data frames. Each mask_df is the same shape as df. The colors will depend on which masks are true/false.

```
rndm = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-15,15,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
rndm_mask1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1],size=(100, 4), p=[2./3, 1./3]), columns=list('ABCD'))
rndm_mask2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1],size=(100, 4), p=[1./3, 2./3]), columns=list('ABCD'))
rndm_mask3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1],size=(100, 4), p=[2./3, 1./3]), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

### Logic

Basically:

1. if rndm_mask1 is **true** (and rndm_mask2 and 3 are **FALSE**), background is red
2. if rndm_mask2 is **true**, yellow
3. if rndm_mask3 is **true**, blue
4. if rndm_mask1 AND rndm_mask2 are **true**, orange
5. if rndm_mask2 AND rndm_mask3 are **true**, green
6. if rndm_mask1 AND rndm_mask3 are **true**, purple

### Problem:

I'm not sure how to chain all these styling logics into one cohesive function. The `pd.DataFrame.style.apply()` method requires list like outputs which I'm having trouble with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the mask to boolean with `astype(bool)` then use `np.select`

```py
rndm_mask1 = rndm_mask1.astype(bool)
rndm_mask2 = rndm_mask2.astype(bool)
rndm_mask3 = rndm_mask3.astype(bool)

def styler(df):
    color = 'background-color: {}'.format

    m = np.select([rndm_mask1 & (~rndm_mask2) & (~rndm_mask3),
                   rndm_mask2, rndm_mask3,
                   rndm_mask1 & rndm_mask2,
                   rndm_mask2 & rndm_mask3,
                   rndm_mask1 & rndm_mask3],
                  list(map(color, ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'purple'])),
              default='')

    return m


rndm = rndm.style.apply(styler, axis=None)
```